# Proper file specification for python dotenv CLI?

Tags: python, shell, dotenv

My team's project uses the python `dotenv` package for managing environment variables in code, and this works quite well. For testing purposes, I'd like to run some shell commands (using the DB) drawing on the same set of environment variables. The  [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/#command-line-interface) doesn't provide enough details to use the `-f`/`--file` option correctly. With a directory structure like

```
/home/username
├── config
│   └── .env-prod
└── .env
```

This works, grabbing from `.env`:

```
$ dotenv get DB_HOST
```

These don't:

```sh
$ dotenv -f ./config/.env-prod get DB_HOST
$ dotenv -f ~/config/.env-prod get DB_HOST
$ dotenv -f=./config/.env-prod get DB_HOST
$ dotenv --file=./config/.env-prod get DB_HOST
$ dotenv get DB_HOST -f ./config/.env-prod
$ dotenv  get DB_HOST --file=./config/.env-prod
```

I also tested the file option with `list` and `run` and those doesn't work any better.

Answer (score 1):

Only full absolute paths are permitted. `dotenv --file=~/config/.env-prod get DB_HOST` does not work, but `dotenv --file=/home/username/config/.env-prod get DB_HOST` does.

Comment: Yuck. Seems like a rather arbitrary and  irritating limitation.